# Understanding cairo_scale()

Tags: c, cairo

I am trying to understand the `cairo_scale()` function. There is a [documentation](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html) but I still don't get it.

Consider the following code

```
cairo_scale(cr,1./WIDTH,1./HEIGHT);
cairo_move_to(cr,0,0);
cairo_line_to(cr,1,1);
cairo_stroke(cr); //draw a line across the image
```

and (the working version) without scale

```
cairo_move_to(cr,0,0);
cairo_line_to(cr,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
cairo_stroke(cr);
```

As far as I understand `cairo_scale(1/width,1/height)` should scale all following verbs, so the x and y ranges are from 0 to 1 (instead of 0 to WIDTH and 0 to HEIGHT).

Unfortunately it does not work and I cannot see anything. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `cairo_scale()` as multiplying all the following coordinates with its argument.

In your case this means you are drawing a line from `(0, 0)` to `(1/width, 1/height)` which is less than a pixel.

You want to call `cairo_scale(cr, WIDTH, HEIGHT)` instead.